# How can I fix the issue where List in SwiftUI running on IOS disappears other view in IOS 15.4 while it works fine on IOS 16.4?

Tags: listview, swiftui, ios-15.4

List in swiftUI running on IOS make above view disappear in IOS 15.4, on IOS 16.4 everything is ok,is that have anyway to fix this issue on IOS 15.4

this is the IOS 16.4 image [IOS 16.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97zk4.png)

this is the app on IOS 15.4 [IOS 15.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USri1.gif)

```
struct SettingView: View {
    // MARK: - properties
    @State private var isOnTimer: Bool = false
    // MARK: - display file name as song title
    @State private var isOnDisPlayFileName: Bool = false
    @State private var isOnAllowDupicate: Bool = false
    let webServerWrapper = WebServerWrapper()
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            VStack {
                CustomNavigtionBar(title: "Setting")
                    .frame(height: 70)
                List {
                    Text("hello there")
                    
                    Text("hello there")
                    
                    Text("hello there")
                    
                    Text("hello there")
                    
                    Text("hello there")
                    
                    Text("hello there")
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, 47)
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
        }
        
    }
}
```

show UI like app on IOS 16.4